# Opening and reading a CSV file without sheet name

Tags: vba, excel, csv

I'm trying to write VBA Codes that will read a given CSV file name and do some changes to the data before writing into another CSV file.

```
Set oSht_Input = Workbooks.Open(file_Path, UpdateLinks:=False).Worksheets(extractDataFile.convertedSheetName)
lastRow = oSht_Input.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For Rows = 2 To lastRow
    extractedDataFileRecord.Variable1 = CStr(oSht_Input.Cells(Rows, 1))

.... code continues
```

This code is working fine generally.

However, the flaw is that CSV files will just copy the file name and place into the sheet name. Therefore I can safely assume that the variable *convertedSheetName* is equivalent to the filename provided.

This code will work if the file name is short enough to be copied into the sheet name. However if the file name is too long, the filename gets cut off within the sheet name, thus I am not able to get the correct reference to set the Worksheet object.

Is there a better way to actually get the sheet reference, so that I can read the Cell Values within the sheet?

Comment: If you are using `Workbooks.Open` then the process is essentially a File ► Open as opposed to an import to an existing or new worksheet. There will be only one worksheet when a CSV is open in this manner. Use  `Sheets(1)` worksheet object reference or the `Sheet1` sheet codename to reference it.

Comment: @Jeeped thanks! Sorry I'm a little new to VBA; so do I edit the codes to Workbooks.Open().Sheets(1) ?

Comment: A CSV is just a text file. You don't need to import it into Excel to work on it. You can use an excel macro to change the text file directly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Workbooks.Open then the process is essentially a File ► Open as opposed to an import to an existing or new worksheet. There will be only one worksheet when a CSV is open in this manner. Use `Sheets(1)` worksheets object collection reference or the `Sheet1` sheet codename to reference it. Example:

```
Dim rw As Long, lastRow As Long, file_Path As String, wb As Workbook, oSht_Input As Worksheet

file_Path = "something"
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(file_Path, UpdateLinks:=False)
Set oSht_Input = wb.Sheets(1)

With oSht_Input
    lastRow = .Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    For rw = 2 To lastRow
        'do stuff to .Cells or .Range here
        extractedDataFileRecord.Variable1 = CStr(.Cells(rw, 1))
    Next rw
End With

Set oSht_Input = Nothing
Set wb = Nothing
```

That should get you going. I've used the worksheet reference in a `With ... End With` so that subsequent .cells and .range references need only be prefaced with a period to show the parent.

Comment: That could probably use a `wb.Close, False` before setting wb to nothing and leaving the sub.

Comment: Thank you @Jeeped, works great! Can't believe I couldn't figure out this simple solution